# Global cache object keeps adding items

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, caching, httpruntime.cache

I noticed that in my ASP.NET web application, the internal global cache object keeps adding items like:
System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceData:/mypages/default.aspx. Note that I do have a folder "mypages" with a default.aspx in it. Why is this page being added in ASP.NET cache the moment I access it? While debugging in detail, I noticed many more pages being added in the cache. Why is ASP.NET adding my app page links in cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because OutputCaching is enabled on your web site. ASP.NET caches pages for faster performance.